# Github Deployment for Azure Bot, Thread Aborted failure

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, botframework

I have a basic bot that I am trying to deploy from GitHub, I get this:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.8.2.
Restoring NuGet package WindowsAzure.Storage.9.2.0.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.compilers/2.8.2/microsoft.net.compilers.2.8.2.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/windowsazure.storage/9.2.0/windowsazure.storage.9.2.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/windowsazure.storage/9.2.0/windowsazure.storage.9.2.0.nupkg 86ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.compilers/2.8.2/microsoft.net.compilers.2.8.2.nupkg 102ms
Installing WindowsAzure.Storage 9.2.0.
Installing Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.8.2.
Thread was being aborted.
Thread was being aborted.
```

I do not know what to do, or how to troubleshoot. I originally thought the error was due to authentication, but this does not seem to be the case. Asking Microsoft Knowledge center suggests it may be due to having too many large NuGet packages, however, I don't know how to find out which ones I am not using so I can get rid of them. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/adityajariwala/bhs-skype-bot)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed too.

Answer (score 2):

> Thread was being aborted.

It seems that you set up continuous deployment using GitHub and deploy a bot application from your GitHub repo, and "***Thread was being aborted error***" error is thrown while installing packages.

I had same issue when I'm using free tier, you can try to scale up your [app service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview-readme?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#app-service-plan) tier, and then redeploy your bot app to check if it works.

Besides, if possible, you can try to deploy your bot application using other approaches. For example, deploy it from a local Git Repo or Visual Studio etc.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your steps and it took about 42 mins for the repo to update from GitHub with the same packages you have listed, though I was successful. It could be a factor of internet speed and hitting some internal Azure time out.

It's not ideal, but I would suggest you perform an initial publish from Visual Studio to ensure the referenced nuget packages are installed. After that point, utilize CD in Azure to pull from your Git repo. I tried this and was able to avoid long deploys/aborted threads yet maintained new changes following the initial VS publish.

This isn't a Bot Framework issue, so I would also suggest reaching out to the Azure team as this may be indicative of a larger issue. The more voices heard, the more attention they will give to it.